# Android Compare Strings from HttpResponse

Tags: android, string, comparison, httpresponse

I'm having a curious problem, i have two apps (Web and Android), the first always response in `text/plain` with the following sintax

If the business logic is successfully the response is

```
OK
2013-04-01 14:31:26
```

if fail

```
ERROR
TypeError:MessageError
```

now the web app es working fine the problem is when i'm going to read the response in my android device

```
final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
BufferedReader buffer;
String line = null;

try {
    buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent()), 2048);

    // Read first line
    line = buffer.readLine();
    Log.i(TAG, "Result : '" + line + "'");
    if(line == "OK") {
        // To something with the following lines
    } else {
        while(null != (line = buffer.readLine()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "ERROR: " + line);
        }
    }
} catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
} catch (IOException e1) {
}
```

the problem `line` never is equals to `OK` event if the line `Log.i(TAG, "Result : '" + line + "'")` prints `Result : 'OK'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java you have to use .equals() to compare strings...

So your code should look like this:

```
if(line.equals("OK")) {
```